# IOS how to insert array to SOAP message

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, web-services, soap

I have an array that contains some index inside. When i log it out it looks like this:

```
item pass: (
    80340025,
    80319340,
    80251277
)
```

My array is declared as NSAAray

Then I need to make a soap call to insert this each index of this array into the soap message. The question is how?

Here is my soap message.

```
 NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
                             "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
                             "<soap:Body>"
                             " <IncidentQuery xmlns=\"https://www.monitoredsecurity.com/\">"
                             "<IncidentNumber>%d</IncidentNumber>"
                             "<MaxSignatures></MaxSignatures>"
                             "</IncidentQuery>"
                             "</soap:Body>"
                             "</soap:Envelope>", item_pass];



    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.monitoredsecurity.com/SWS/incidents.asmx"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[soapMessage length]];


    [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue: @"https://www.monitoredsecurity.com/IncidentQuery" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];







    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    [connection start];

    if(connection)
    {
        _webResponseData = [NSMutableData data] ;


    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Connection is NULL");
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to insert 3 numbers to 1 soap? Or each number for each request? What's the problem with your code?

Comment: i want to insert 3 numbers to 1 soap. the code has no problem to insert one number. But i want to pass in 3 numbers into this soap but it fails as i don't know how.

Comment: I see the `soapMessage` just have 1 place to put number in? What format do you want?

Comment: %d is the place where i pass in the number of array but i don't know how

Comment: You want "<IncidentNumber>80340025,
    80319340,
    80251277</IncidentNumber>" ?

Comment: you can convert your array into string then this string can be inserted in your soap message easily with all numbers of array.

Comment: i want the soap to run 3 times depending on how many index are inside the array. each time place the value of the index inside <IncidentNumber>

Answer (score 0):

do like this

```
-(void)SoapCallingMethod
{
  for(int i=0;i<array.count;i++)
  {
     [self yourSoapMethod:[yourArray objectAtIndex:i]];
  }
}

-(void)yourSoapMethod:(NSInteger )indexNumber
{
  yourSoapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:"%d",indexNumber];

  // Rest Steps
}
```

Comment: The IndexNumber needs to be an integer because my soap request parameter only accepts integer